# Getting Updated Value from Input Field from Reactive Forms Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi i have reactive form which is binded with data.I need to update the form after submitting i should get the value which i changed.

html code:

```
   <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="formEdited()">
                   <mat-form-field>
                       <mat-label>Student ID</mat-label>
                         <input type="text"  id="studentID" class="ndi-input" 
                           required formControlName="studentID" autocomplete="off"
                                name="studentID" matInput matInput-warning>
                     </mat-form-field>
                     <mat-form-field>
                          <mat-label>Class ID</mat-label>
                           <input type="text"  id="classID" required 
                                  formControlName="classID" autocomplete="off"
                                name="classID" matInput matInput-warning>
                      </mat-form-field>
        <form>
```

ts code:

```
   this.editForm.patchValue({
          studentID: "test",
          classID: "demo"
   )}
  formEdited(){
     this.editForm.value;
   }
```

Instead of getting single single control value how can i get the values updated in the form at once.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: this.editForm.controls['studentID'].value can get you the value.

Answer (score 0):

using formGroup with react form is recommended. Hope this helps

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

    <mat-form-field class="form-element">
      <input matInput placeholder="Part Number" formControlName="partNumber">
</form>
// you can use ngAfterViewInit() to test that it sets the value
YourMethodToSetValue(){
    console.log(this.formGroup.controls)
    this.formGroup.controls.partNumber.setValue('YOUR VALUE HERE...')
    /* this.formGroup.controls.partNumber.setValue(this.formGroup.controls.partNumber.value);
    console.log(this.formGroup.controls.partNumber.value)*/
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'partNumber': 'default',
  });
}
```